# what it is meant <> and @ before variable in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new to raw sql query. i want to know what `@` before variable in mysql? and <> .

i found `<>` meant notequal if yes then what about `!=`

here is my sql query...

```
if (@leave_name <> "CL") then
    select trans_id into @trans_id from emp_leave 
        where emp_id = in_emp_id and leave_name = @leave_name;
end if;
```

Comment: `<>` is ANSI SQL, `!=` is deprecated.

Comment: what is wrong in it to get downvote?

Comment: @ is use for the variable , check this link : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 1):

`@` signals a sql variable. You can find out more about variables [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

`<>` is the 'correct' way to mean `not equal`.
 `!=` is now deprecated.